# Bootstrap localhost error

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

My website is running with phpstorm's editor's localhot  with any error .

> http://localhost:63342/html/Bag%C4%B1s/bagisyap.html
>   on the other hand ; if i want to start with only my localhost 
>   http://localhost/Bag%C4%B1s/index.html
>   i can not connect bootstrap 's argumant . how i can i solve that ?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bağış Sitesi</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Bagıs/public/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Bagıs/public/css/main.css">

    <!-- Owl Carousel -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Bagıs/public/css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Bagıs/public/css/owl.theme.css">
</head>
<body id="index">   

    <div class="container main-nav">
        <div class="row margin-bottom-zero">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <nav class="navbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Anasayfa</a></li>
                        <li><a href="nedenyardimetmeliyim.html">Neden yardım etmeliyim</a></li>
                        <li><a href="bagisyap.html">Bağış Yap</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ihtiyacsahipleri.html">İhtiyaç sahipleri</a></li>
                        <li><a href="hakkimizda.html">Hakkımızda</a></li>
                        <li><a href="hakkimizda.html#tab3">İletişim</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right user-login-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                              <span class="caret"></span>
                          </a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="giris-yap" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal-box" class="list-group-item">Giriş</a></li>
                            <li><a href="yenikayit.html">Kayıt Ol</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row panel">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="../Bagıs/public/img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">


        <div class="row white-box-style min-row-height">

            <form action="bagısyap.php" method="POST">

                <div class="col-xs-4 choose-category">

                    <h4>Kategori Seçin</h4>
                    <select class="form-control" name="category">
                        <option value="0">Kategori Seçin</option>
                        <option value="1">Elbise</option>
                        <option value="2">Teknoloji</option>
                        <option value="3">Mobilya</option>
                        <option value="3">Küçük Ev Aletleri</option>
                    </select>

                    <select class="form-control" name="category">
                        <option value="0">Alt Kategori Seçin</option>
                        <option value="1">Telefon</option>
                        <option value="2">Laptop</option>
                        <option value="3">Monitör</option>
                        <option value="3">Telefon Kılıfları</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-8">

                    <div class="row">
                    <h4> &nbsp; </h4>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="../Bagıs/public/img/empty-image.jpg" alt="...">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                             <textarea name="desc" class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Ürün hakkında kısa bir açıklama"></textarea>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1">
                            Bu ürünü ismimi gizleyerek (anonim olarak) ekleyin
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Tamamla</button>
                </div>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="login-modal-box" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <form action="#giris-kontrol" method="POST">


            <div class="modal-dialog user-login-box-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Kullanıcı Giriş Paneli</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Eposta Adresiniz</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Şifre</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                          </div>

                          <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                              <input type="checkbox"> Beni hatırla
                            </label>
                          </div>
</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <a href="#user-profile" class="btn btn-primary"> Giriş Yap</a>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</form>
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
<!-- Include Jquery -->
    <script src="../Bagıs/public/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="../Bagıs/public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Bagıs/public/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Bagıs/public/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: http://localhost:63342/html/Bag%C4%B1s/bagisyap.html]
[image: http://localhost/Bag%C4%B1s/index.html]

Comment: Use only "standard" ascii characters in addresses. Check for your local and remote hosts (ftp, ssh client) to be set to use the same encoding (utf-8) everywhere.

Comment: how can i do that ? do i have to change folder's name?

Comment: i think error is in here !<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/owl.carousel.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/owl.theme.css">

Comment: You trying to connect your own libraries from?

Comment: yes actually i dont know